# Just a curiosity about an integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory

does the fact that the number $$\frac{\pi\displaystyle\prod_{n\geq1}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{k2^n}\right)}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{k})}$$ is always an integer for any k, has any interest.
Bests 
Riadh

Comment: In fact it seems to be $k$ (of course you must assume $k \ne -1,0,1$).

Comment: This is not a math question, please reformulate it

Comment: @Norbert I'm assuming they mean to ask why it is always an integer for (assuming) integer $k$.

Answer (score 7):

This is not really about integers.  It comes from the formula
$$ \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x} = \prod_{k=1}^\infty \cos\left(\frac{x}{2^k}\right)$$
See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Infinite_product_formulae